# Publish SSRS report to SharePoint document library

Tags: document-library, reporting-services

This question is a copy of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232202/publish-ssrs-report-to-sharepoint-document-library) on stack overflow. Didnt know this forum existed until now.

I cannot find a way to publish/deploy my reports to a SharePoint document library. I have exhausted all my options as I see it. Please help me!

My server setup:

- Windows server 2012
- SharePoint 2013
- SQL Server 2012 (on different server also Windows 2012)

My client setup:

- Windows 7 32 Bit
- Visual Studio 2013
- Office 2010
- No SharePoint OpenDocument Class ActiveX component installed (tried repairing Office with no luck)

What I have done so far:

- Installed Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint 2013 with Rssharepoint.msi
- Configured the add-in according to [http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/...](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25255.sharepoint-2013-how-to-set-up-configure-and-test-sql-2012-sp1-ssrs-with-sharepoint-2013-sp1.aspx). Not the installation part.

**Upload .rds file**

I have a bunch of working reports which I can deploy to a stand alone Reporting Services Server installed on the "different" server mentioned above. When I upload one of the reports (.rdl) to a document library in SharePoint and click it I see the familiar SSRS page but an error is displayed:

> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

That report is a test report which does not require a data source and should work. I have not found any logs that tell me what is wrong.

**Add new document in SharePoint document library**

I also tried adding the SQL Server content types to the document library. Then I get additional New Document buttons for Report, Data Source and Data Model. None of these work and gives me this error alert:

> 'New Document' requires a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible application and web browser. To add a document to this document library, click the 'Upload Document' button.

I installed Report Builder 3.0 both on client PC and server with same result. I also confirmed the setting for SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application under Central Administration.

- Enable Load Report Definition, check
- Enable Remote Errors, check
- Enable Test Connection Detailed Errors, check
- Enable Report Builder download, check

**Deploy from Visual Studio 2013**

Last resort before posting this was to try deploy the reports from Visual Studio. I did the steps required in this page, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283155.aspx. Missing from this instruction is the box TargetServerVersion. In my installation I can choose from either *SQL Server 2008 R2 or later*, *SQL Server 2008* or *Detect version...*. Neither of these seem to work and I get this error regardless of what I choose.

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Unexpected type T: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceContract.IReportServiceManagement

My questions summarized:

- Where do I find logs for the SSRS errors in SharePoint?
- Why cant I create data sources in my SharePoint document library from the 'New Document' button?
- Why cant I deploy a report from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying you skipped the "installation" part?

You have not set it up correctly.  SharePoint does not work in that fashion with Reporting Services in native mode.  SSRS has it's own web interface and report manager.  Reporting Services integrated mode MUST be installed on a SharePoint server - it utilizes the server API's to work.

If all you want to do is have a window into the SSRS server there are different webparts you install from SQL (SPViewer) - This gives you report viewer and explorer (for finding and viewing reports), and you can launch report builder if enabled.  But it's all launched from SSRS web site.

**EDIT**

Apparently this answer is not clear.

You need to follow all the instruction - including deploying SSRS integrated if you want to manage reports inside SharePoint.

If you want to use an existing SSRS server then you just deploy SPViewer webparts that come with SQL server. Again - note this is NOT the same package you deploy with the integrated tools.  You will NOT manage reports from inside SharePoint.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218795%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I skipped the installation part in that specific tutorial. What I did do, as described in the question, is _Installed Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint 2013 with Rssharepoint.msi_ on the SharePoint server. My goal is to render reports inside SharePoint without a stand alone SSRS server. On the SQL server machine (different machine) SSRS is installed (stand alone), can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes - that's what I'm saying.  If you want "integrated" functionality you must use SSRS installed in integrated mode.  If you just want to view reports from existing SSRS server - you need to use the SPViewer web parts which is a different install.

Comment: Manually deploying the RS add-in is really only useful if you are running a separate stand-alone RS server. It adds tools an web parts that will let you view reports from that server through the SharePoint UI. If you want to actually manage and run your reports through SharePoint then you need to install SSRS in Integrated Mode on your SharePoint server like Martin suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set `TargetReportPartFolder` and `TargetDatasetFolder` from your Property Pages Configuration.

Refer This video-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMEIx3S4gqs

Comment: Did as Travis in the video with the result `The specified TargetServerURL is not valid. Specify a valid URL for a report server in the deployment settings.`

Comment: I used the same URL for all Target... accept TargetServerURL and TargetServerVersion. The URL used in all Target... is `http://livs784/SKaPa Rapporter` and TargetServerURL is set to `http://livs784/`.